# How do I fix a g++ memory range overlap?

Tags: c++, linux, memory, g++, range

I developed a C++ program that works perfectly in Visual Studio that takes an array of ints, two arrays of C strings, and a large C string, and tries to find if the large C string contains any of the other C strings within a certain distance of each other.

EDIT: Since this a school assignment, I'm restrained to using C strings instead of std::string and strcopy instead of memmove.

When I run the program on g++, I get the following error message:

```
==17764==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: strcpy-param-overlap: memory ranges [0x7fff7213d993,0x7fff7213d994) and [0x7fff7213d993, 0x7fff7213d994) overlap
    #0 0x7fa2141eec11 in __interceptor_strcpy ../../../../gcc-4.9.2/libsanitizer/asan/asan_interceptors.cc:486
    #1 0x402b2a in standardizeRules(int*, char (*) [21], char (*) [21], int) (/w/home.02/cs/ugrad/justinn/match+0x402b2a)
    #2 0x40176d in main (/w/home.02/cs/ugrad/justinn/match+0x40176d)
    #3 0x376f01ed1c in __libc_start_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x376f01ed1c)
    #4 0x4011f8 (/w/home.02/cs/ugrad/justinn/match+0x4011f8)

Address 0x7fff7213d993 is located in stack of thread T0 at offset 787 in frame
    #0 0x401347 in main (/w/home.02/cs/ugrad/justinn/match+0x401347)

  This frame has 7 object(s):
    [32, 48) 'test1dist'
    [96, 144) 'distance'
    [192, 276) 'test1w1'
    [320, 404) 'test1w2'
    [448, 577) 'doc'
    [640, 892) 'word1' <== Memory access at offset 787 is inside this variable
    [928, 1180) 'word2'
HINT: this may be a false positive if your program uses some custom stack unwind mechanism or swapcontext
      (longjmp and C++ exceptions *are* supported)
Address 0x7fff7213d993 is located in stack of thread T0 at offset 787 in frame
    #0 0x401347 in main (/w/home.02/cs/ugrad/justinn/match+0x401347)

  This frame has 7 object(s):
    [32, 48) 'test1dist'
    [96, 144) 'distance'
    [192, 276) 'test1w1'
    [320, 404) 'test1w2'
    [448, 577) 'doc'
    [640, 892) 'word1' <== Memory access at offset 787 is inside this variable
    [928, 1180) 'word2'
HINT: this may be a false positive if your program uses some custom stack unwind mechanism or swapcontext
      (longjmp and C++ exceptions *are* supported)
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: strcpy-param-overlap ../../../../gcc-4.9.2/libsanitizer/asan/asan_interceptors.cc:486 __interceptor_strcpy
==17764==ABORTING
```

What causes this error and how do I fix it?

Thanks!

EDIT:
Here is the code:

```
int standardizeRules(int distance[], char word1[][MAX_WORD_LENGTH + 1], char word2[][MAX_WORD_LENGTH + 1], int nRules)
{
    int validCheck = nRules; //validCheck holds the number of actual valid rules to avoid checking known bad rules
    for (int a = 0; a < validCheck; a++) //converts every letter in every string to lowercase
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < MAX_WORD_LENGTH; b++)
        {
            word1[a][b] = tolower(word1[a][b]);
            word2[a][b] = tolower(word2[a][b]);
        }
    }
    for (int count = 0; count < validCheck; count++) //repeat rule testing, if a repeat is found it sets distance to 0 so code automatically filters it out
    {
        for (int x = count + 1; x < validCheck; x++) //compares current string to all other strings behind it in both arrays
        {
            bool repeat = false;
            //cerr << "Testing: " << x << endl;
            if (strcmp(word1[count], word1[x]) == 0)
            {
                if (strcmp(word2[count], word2[x]) == 0)
                {
                    //cerr << "Repeat rule" << endl;
                    repeat = true;
                }
            }
            else if (strcmp(word1[count], word2[x]) == 0)
            {
                if (strcmp(word2[count], word1[x]) == 0)
                {
                    //cerr << "Repeat rule" << endl;
                    repeat = true;
                }
            }
            else if (strcmp(word2[count], word1[x]) == 0)
            {
                if (strcmp(word1[count], word2[x]) == 0)
                {
                    //cerr << "Repeat rule" << endl;
                    repeat = true;
                }
            }
            else if (strcmp(word2[count], word2[x]) == 0)
            {
                if (strcmp(word1[count], word1[x]) == 0)
                {
                    //cerr << "Repeat rule" << endl;
                    repeat = true;
                }
            }
            if (repeat) //tests to see which distance is lesser, then sets that to 0
            {
                //cerr << "Repeat testing" << endl;
                if (distance[count] < distance[x])
                {
                    distance[count] = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    distance[x] = 0;
                }
            }
            //cerr << "X:" << x << endl;
        }
        //cerr << "Done with repeat" << endl;
        bool replace = false;
        if (distance[count] < 1) //non-positive distance check
        {
            //cerr << "Bad distance: " << distance[count] << endl;
            replace = true;
        }
        if (strlen(word1[count]) == 0 || strlen(word2[count]) == 0) //empty string check
        {
            //cerr << "Empty string" << endl;
            replace = true;
        }
        for (int charPos = 0; charPos < MAX_WORD_LENGTH; charPos++) //non-alphabetical check
        {
            if (word1[count][charPos] != '\0' && word2[count][charPos] != '\0')
            {
                if (!(isalpha(word1[count][charPos]) && isalpha(word2[count][charPos])))
                {
                    //cerr << "Bad character 1: " << word1[count][charPos] << ", Bad character 2: " << word2[count][charPos] << endl;
                    replace = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (replace) //if bad rule, swaps current rule with last valid (or unchecked) rule
        {
            //cerr << "Begin" << endl;
            for (int x = 0; x < validCheck; x++)
            {
                //cerr << "Dist: " << distance[x] << ", word1: " << word1[x] << ", word2: " << word2[x] << endl;
            }
            //cerr << endl;
            int distReplace = distance[validCheck - 1];
            distance[validCheck - 1] = distance[count];
            distance[count] = distReplace;
            char word1Rep[MAX_WORD_LENGTH + 1];
            char word2Rep[MAX_WORD_LENGTH + 1];
            strcpy(word1Rep, word1[validCheck - 1]);
            strcpy(word2Rep, word2[validCheck - 1]);
            strcpy(word1[validCheck - 1], word1[count]);
            strcpy(word2[validCheck - 1], word2[count]);
            strcpy(word1[count], word1Rep);
            strcpy(word2[count], word2Rep);
            for (int x = 0; x < validCheck; x++)
            {
                //cerr << "Dist: " << distance[x] << ", word1: " << word1[x] << ", word2: " << word2[x] << endl;
            }
            validCheck--;
            count--;
            //cerr << "End" << endl;
        }
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < validCheck; x++)
    {
        //cerr << "Dist: " << distance[x] << ", word1: " << word1[x] << ", word2: " << word2[x] << endl;
    }
    //cerr << "validCheck: " << validCheck << endl;
    return validCheck;
}

int determineQuality(const int distance[], const char word1[][MAX_WORD_LENGTH + 1], const char word2[][MAX_WORD_LENGTH + 1], int nRules, const char document[])
{
    //cerr << "Checkpoint A" << endl;
    int quality = 0; //counter for matches
    char words[200][200]; //array to hold all words in document
    int count = 0;
    int arrayPos = 0;
    while (count < strlen(document)) //loop through document
    {
        //cerr << "Checkpoint B" << endl;
        int charPos = 0;
        while (count < strlen(document) && document[count] != ' ') //split document up into words and record words in array
        {
            //cerr << "Checkpoint C: " << count << endl;
            if (isalpha(document[count]) && charPos < 200) //record only alphabetical characters
            {
                words[arrayPos][charPos] = tolower(document[count]);
                charPos++;
            }
            count++;
        }
        count++;
        words[arrayPos][charPos] = '\0'; //end each word with a null byte
        //cerr << "Word: " << words[arrayPos] << endl;
        arrayPos++;
    }
    for (int ruleCount = 0; ruleCount < nRules; ruleCount++) //compare rules to words
    {
        bool match = false; //boolean to record if rule has a match or not
        for (int wordCount = 0; wordCount <= arrayPos; wordCount++)
        {
            if (strcmp(word1[ruleCount], words[wordCount]) == 0) //if word1 finds a match, look for a match for word2 within distance
            {
                int beginning = wordCount - distance[ruleCount];
                if (beginning < 0)
                {
                    beginning = 0;
                }
                int end = wordCount + distance[ruleCount];
                if (end >= arrayPos)
                {
                    end = arrayPos;
                }
                for (int arrayCheck = beginning; arrayCheck <= end; arrayCheck++)
                {
                    if (strcmp(word2[ruleCount], words[arrayCheck]) == 0)
                    {
                        match = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (strcmp(word2[ruleCount], words[wordCount]) == 0) //if word2 find a match, look for a match for word1 within distance
            {
                int beginning = wordCount - distance[ruleCount];
                if (beginning < 0)
                {
                    beginning = 0;
                }
                int end = wordCount + distance[ruleCount];
                if (end >= arrayPos)
                {
                    end = arrayPos;
                }
                for (int arrayCheck = beginning; arrayCheck <= end; arrayCheck++)
                {
                    if (strcmp(word1[ruleCount], words[arrayCheck]) == 0)
                    {
                        match = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (match) //if rule had a match, increment quality
        {
            quality++;
        }
    }
    return quality;
}
```

Comment: Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and compile your code with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Use also a debugger (`gdb`) and notably its watchpoints. You might have some [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) somewhere!

Comment: Show your source code. Looks like you are using `strcpy` wrongly (with overlapping memory zones). Consider using `memmove`. BTW in C++ you should use `std::string`

Comment: Sounds like a buffer overrun, meaning you are accessing an array index outside of the array boundaries. Possibly you just got lucky in Visual Studio. It is a bit hard to say without seeing some the code.

Comment: Try to identify the offending part of your source code and add a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question.

Comment: Please show your `standardizeRules` function.

Comment: You have not explained why you're using `strcpy` to begin with (the description of your goal does not suggest that you need to use this function at any point). That being said, if you do need to use it for possibly overlapping strings, then you should call `memmove(dst,src,strlen(src)+1)` instead.

Comment: I updated the post with the code for everyone. Thanks!

Also, to those saying I should use C++ strings, the assignment was specifically to use C strings.

Comment: Your problem occurs here:

            strcpy(word1[validCheck - 1], word1[count]);
            strcpy(word2[validCheck - 1], word2[count]);


Your code is quite aweful and not compilable as it stands.

Comment: @AhmedMasud If you have the solution you should put it in an answer.

Comment: @AhmedMasud Can you elaborate?

Comment: Can you please put your entire program code so that it's compilable

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help.

After further investigation I found that the error was a result of using strcpy() with the same destination as the source.